# Log all AJAX requests going through $httpBackend

Tags: ajax, angularjs, httpbackend

How do I log all requests that go through `$httpBackend`? I know how to give a mock response with `.respond()`, how to let the request pass through with `.passThrough()`, but how can I only intercept the request to log it and then let it pass through?

Comment: Minor addendum, in case it is relevant: I'm using `protractor` and it hangs waiting for the page to load and I want to see which requests are not fulfilled (mocked/stubbed).

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but provided you're calling `$httpBackend.flush()` all your unexpected requests should get logged to the console by the karma runner.